# Premissions needed to launch COM as "The launching user" identity?

Tags: windows, permissions, dcom

Solved: added `full control` over `C:\Program Files\Application` folder to group containing "The launching user".

---

Using `dcomcnfg` I can configure a application identity, when launched from another application as COM.

[image: DCOM Config]

When `The launching user` user is member of `Administrators` group my application can create COM object, but I want that my user have as low permissions as possible.

Using `secpol` I have added group with my user to:

- Impersonate a client after authentication
- Log on as batch job (needed for non interactive session)
- Log on as service (needed, my application runs as service)
- Obtain an impersonation token (...)

But that not resolved my problem. What `secpol` or other permissions are needed?

Note: I can't use other `Identity` options, It must be launching user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the security settings for the COM object itself. By default the Administrators group has Full permissions and the Users group has read. Here's the delta in permissions. You'll have to experiment with the perms to get the minimum you need.

```
Permissions  Admins Users
Full Control    +   -
Query Value     +   +
Set Value       +   -
Create Subkey   +   -
Enum Subkeys    +   +
Notify          +   +
Create Link     +   -
Delete          +   -
Write DAC       +   +
Write Owner     +   +
Read Control    +   +
```

Comment: I'll try with Subinacl http://www.robvanderwoude.com/subinacl.php